# Generating forms that use an MVC Web API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an interface that customizes and generates forms for customers to use on their own site. When a user logs in to the interface, he can create a form, add or remove fields from existing forms, and the system will generate the file.

I want to know what's the best approach for doing this. Making these forms independent and just use HTML/Javascript? or have them part of the overall MVC solution inside a Views folder so it can have server side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabily the best way is not to store the entire form, but having some metadata that describe the forms, then generate the gui dynamically. There are many ways to doing this, it basically depends on your skill, and your specifics, personally im developing something similar right now and i chose Angular2.
Here an example:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Comment: Are you stacking it with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I use ado cause i'm migrating from another older project, and i have the most part of my server side code already done.
You can use whatever you want for persistence.

Comment: Thank you, I used a library called MVC Dynamic Forms that does what you described. I create the form in the controller, then serialize the object to a steam of bytes and store everything in the db.